# Non-associative nested 2 level array PHP

Tags: php, json

I am needing to produce a javascript json string. It expects some data in the format like

`[[4, 34, "Hello"],[5, 23, "World"],[8, 21, "Today"]]`

i.e. Not as an associated array.

The data is coming from PHP where I have these 3 columns defined as part of an object. However I don't know how to produce such an array as doing something like (oversimplified mapping of phpobject to json data here but gives you an idea)

```
$json = array();
foreach($phpObject->getRows as $row)
{
    $json[][0] = $row[0];
    $json[][1] = $row[1];
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Gives you an associated array. Given some hardcoded data you'd just do something like

```
echo json_encode(array(array(4, 34, 'Hello'), array(5, 23, 'World'));
```

However I can't find any way of producing the above 'on the fly'

EDIT: Current Hack around this is

```
<?php $dataset = '['; ?>
<?php foreach ($graph->getRows() as $row) : ?>
<?php $dataset .= '['; ?>
<?php $dataset .= $row[0] . ', '; ?>
<?php $dataset .= $row[1] . ', '; ?>
<?php $dataset .= '"' . $row[2] . '"'; ?>
<?php $dataset .= '],'; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php $dataset = rtrim($dataset, ','); ?>
<?php $dataset .= ']'; ?>
var dataset = <?php echo $dataset; ?>;
```

Comment: What output are you currently getting with your code? To abandon keys, you might find [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values) helpful

Comment: Everytime you do `$json[]` you are adding a new item to the array! So your code above creates 2 items per row. Try doing `$json[]` just once and refer to that one later on with `$json[count($json)-1]`.

Comment: @kingkero I ended up hacking around it pretty badly when I came accross it earlier (see edit)

Comment: Can't you create an array in the foreach (something like: $arr = array($row[0],$row[1],$row[2]);) and then push it into the json array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the values of the row to your json array, letting PHP set the numeric keys.

```
$json = array();
foreach ( $phpObject->getRows as $row ) {
    $json[] = array_values($row);
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Alternatively you can do `$json[] = array($row[0], $row[1]);` if you don't want every value from `$row`

Comment: Yah that's what I'm doing @BrianAdams - thanks both!